# Why does the print function stop working with sleep with the end argument?

Tags: python, output

I was just messing around and I have the following code:

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print('a', end='        ')
    sleep(0.05)
```

For some reason, nothing is printed *until* I  press Ctl+C. Then it prints everything it should have been continually printing. However, if I remove the `end` argument:

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print('a')
    sleep(0.05)
```

It works perfectly. "a" prints every 0.05 seconds.

Also, I don't have the problem with the first code when I leave out `sleep`.

So: *Why does the `end` argument make `sleep` hide output?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python (and other) programs print to the screen, it is first send to a print buffer. When Python find it fittingly, it will flush this buffer onto the screen. I do not know the internal details of this behavior, but you can set the `flush` keyword of the `print` function to `True` to force the flush to happen instantly. Try:

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    print('a', end='        ', flush=True)
    sleep(0.05)
```